# How to convert string HH:MM to Joda Duration?

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a field in a form to state the time duration of an event.
Say, the event is to last 15 mins. So the field will have the following value: 00:15
If it is to last 1 hour: 01:00, etc.

How can I create a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) object with the string "HH:MM"?

Looking at Joda-Time home page, it mentions that it is possible to create a Duration object from specified object using ConverterManager and DurationConverter respectively.

My question is, how can I implement the above interfaces so that I can create a Duration object by passing the a "4:30" parameter?

Thanks in advance,

Lucas

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think a better way would be to use [`PeriodFormatterBuilder`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html) like this:

```
 PeriodFormatter hoursMinutes= new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
     .appendHours()
     .appendSeparator(":")
     .appendMinutes()
     .toFormatter();
```

Then you can parse your strings into `Period` objects and call `toStandardDuration()` on those - or keep working with the `Period`, since that seems to match your use case better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. how would I call that passing the parameters: HH:mm?

Comment: @Lucas: you wouldn't. The API is based on the builder design pattern, not on a pattern string. The code I poses is the equivalent of a HH:mm pattern string.

Comment: Once you have a formatter, you call formatter.parsePeriod("00:15") to get the period object - http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html

Comment: Is there any reason behind the lack of the possibility to use DateTimeFormat for a Period in joda time? One may decide the builder pattern is too verbose for specific purposes and may want to use a simple and straightforward DateTimeFormat to format the given Period (or equivalent)