# Convert time int to minutes seconds hour

Tags: java, math

I'm having some math issues with the devide and modolu operator.

Basically I have to give a format of mmsshh as a input and the output should be something like this: "Hours" + hours + "minutes" + minutes "seconds" + seconds.

So when I would insert 003400 the output should be "hours 0 minutes 0 seconds 34".

The problem is that the 0 is giving me trouble getting these seperate data values.

I've tried the following methods already but they're not working properly.

```
public void setMinutes()
{
    minutes = time / 10000;
}
public int getMinutes()
{
    return minutes;
}
public void setSeconds()
{
    seconds = (time%1E4)/100;
}
public double getSeconds()
{
    return seconds;
}
```

Comment: Minutes, seconds and *then hours*? Really? That's a *thoroughly* bizarre input...

Comment: I would've done it otherwise, but my client insists on this input.

Comment: It's unclear why you've got an API like this - it's weird to have a `set` method with no parameter. Why do you not just have `get` methods which use `time`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this very simple solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "123456";
    String minutes = input.substring(0, 2);
    String seconds = input.substring(2, 4);
    String hours = input.substring(4, 6);
    System.out.println("Hours" + hours + "minutes" + minutes + "seconds" + seconds);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Hours56minutes12seconds34
```

And if you like to get doubles instead of strings do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "123456";
    Double minutes = parseDouble(input.substring(0, 2));
    Double seconds = parseDouble(input.substring(2, 4));
    Double hours = parseDouble(input.substring(4, 6));
    System.out.printf("Hours %.0f Minutes %.0f Seconds %.0f\n", hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

Comment: this solution does not normalize/carry minutes and seconds > 59

Comment: It depends on the specification of mmhhss. I expected them to have values between mm [00 - 59], hh [1 - 24] and ss [0 - 59].

Answer (score 0):

Considering the unconventional input pattern, it would be better to treat the input as as String.
Get the values for hours, minutes and seconds and then do an Integer.parseInt on the value.

Answer (score 0):

Java way is to parse the string using SimpleDateFormat (or time/duration counterpart from Joda, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619730/how-to-convert-string-hhmm-to-joda-duration) ). As a bonus it will detect invalid input such as 246060 for date and xx6060 for duration.